# When is a clique.proposal known to other nodes?

Tags: go-ethereum, proof-of-authority

I do not really understand how a proposal is communicated to the other nodes.

I have 5 nodes in a PoA private ethereum network. I am trying to add 2 nodes on another server. I get this -

```
instance: Geth/v1.8.2-stable-b8b9f7f4/linux-amd64/go1.9.4
coinbase: 0x242f75170b0b38917995724bd5aef1aa07d31fff
at block: 14513 (Tue, 17 Apr 2018 11:13:10 UTC)
 datadir: /home/satoshimaca/blockchain3/node1
 modules: admin:1.0 clique:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

> clique.proposals()
TypeError: 'proposals' is not a function
    at :1:1

> clique.proposals
{
  0xf39995b718ae7a0075557f9781425b92fd8b28a6: true
}
```

but when I attach geth to node 2 I get this -

```
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.8.2-stable-b8b9f7f4/linux-amd64/go1.9.4
coinbase: 0xc7c776a8b564228ecca00c86d1d80b431aa9f4f3
at block: 14578 (Tue, 17 Apr 2018 11:18:35 UTC)
 datadir: /home/satoshimaca/blockchain3/node2
 modules: admin:1.0 clique:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

> clique.proposals
{}
```

When will my proposal be known to node2 or should I manually add to all the nodes?

Also I do not see any reference in my log to the proposal.

Comment: This works for me now by me manually adding all the proposals to every node.

Comment: I think there may be some confusion wrt period = 0 or not. I'm also having trouble when period = 0

Answer (score 0):

`clique.proposals` returns the proposals submitted by the node on which you run the command. Once a proposal has been submitted by the critical mass (IIRC 50% + 1 of the current authority nodes), it is accepted and the given address is added to (`true`) or removed from (`false`) the list of authority nodes (signers).

You can check the current list of authority accounts with `clique.getSigners()`.

See also [consensus/clique/api.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/consensus/clique/api.go).